# Can new users answer questions?

Tags: discussion, support

A friend complains about Stack Exchange because it seems he cannot answer any question before earning points first.

Is he forced to ask a dummy question, earn some points in order to answer questions?

Comment: New users cannot answer protected questions (ones that have attracted enough low quality answers to warrant *protection*). Can you link to what question they wanted to answer?

Comment: Everyone was new at some point.  If a user can't post additional answers their other answers are likely the reason why.

Comment: You sure he doesn't mean that he can't comment, rather than answer? A rep of 50 is required to comment.

Comment: You can't even be bothered to clarify what you mean? That's just a shame.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. He is not. Reputation is not a requirement to ask a question or answer them, unless the question is protected which is quite rare (for example because it has attracted low-quality or spam posts). In that case you need 10 reputation earned on that site (excluding association bonus).

It is possible he is post-banned for a history of low-quality posts, but that is something moderators can tell. Let your friend contact the team using the *Contact Us* in the footer.